# Embed SVG onload event does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I have angular directive:

```
   <div>
     <embed ng-src="{{url}}" id="map" type="image/svg+xml/>
   </div>
```

I need to perform code when svg is loaded, so, i add onload action listener on dom ready

```
    // on dom ready
    $timeout(function(){
      $("#map")[0].onload = onSVGReady;
    });
```

here map is id of the embed element and osSVGReady is action handler.

This approach works when svg was loaded first time and when url changes, onSVGReady handler is not performed.

Btw, when i add onload handler directly to the element it works:

```
<embed ng-src="{{url}}" id="map" type="image/svg+xml" onload="console.log('Yes')"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution: use object instead of embed:

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" ng-attr-data="{{url}}">
```